# Spring boot application Creating Two Database rows

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a `spring boot` application with `MySQL` database. Below method is creating medication's two rows with same fields.

```
    @Override
    @Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
    public MedicationGroup save(MedicationGroup medicationGroup) {
        return medicationRepository.save(medicationGroup);
    }
```

> Medication Group Entity:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Table(name = "medication_group")
@Entity
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class MedicationGroup extends AbstractEntity implements Persistable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2948809916398284974L;

    private Short type;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "patient_id", nullable = false, updatable = false, insertable = false)
    private Patient patient;

    @Column(name = "patient_id")
    private Long patientId;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "medicationGroup", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Prescription> prescriptions;

}
```

> Below rows are created into database :

[image]

Its not happening continually it will happen any time unable to find reason.

Comment: Are you sure the method is not called twice? Try logging something or using a debugger to be sure. Or are you trying to update a `MedicationGroup` object, but your primary key is not set so Hibernate thinks it is a new record?

Comment: please show part of `MedicationGroup` class where entity annotations and id properties are defined

Comment: Show how you are calling `public MedicationGroup save(MedicationGroup medicationGroup) {}`. Which column is your primary key ?

Comment: @Raheela Aslam I do not think this code alone can be a culprit, might be outside of this you are again saving object or playing with non persisted data.

Comment: I have added the MedicationGroup class. Actually its uncertain not happening everytime  i think there is issue of related to Transaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure the method is not called twice. Try  using primary key in one of the fields, so that duplicate data is not stored in the database.